# How to resolve z-index issues in css

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index

I have 3 divisions. Two divs are its children, and one div is their parent. I've set the parent background image, and both children are also seeing it. However, the issue is with the child divs' elements, since I am unable to select or use mouse events on them because of their -1 location. In order to make the background visible on both children, I gave child divs a Z-index of -1. Is there a solution that will allow me to resolve this issue so that i can perform mouse events and select child divs?

```css
/* About us section styles */

.aboutus-contact-us-wrapper {
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1667998641206-3eaa8f7047cd?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=459&q=80');
  background-size:  300px;
  background-position: right center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  
}


.about-us-section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  font-family: 'Lato' !important;
  z-index: -1;
}

.contact-us {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #181f2b;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
  <div class="aboutus-contact-us-wrapper">
        <!-- About Us section -->
        <div class="about-us-section">
           <h1> Cannot select and perform actions </h1>
        </div>

        <!-- About us Section ends here -->

        <!-- Contact us Section  -->
        <div class="contact-us">
          <div class="contact-background">
<a href="https://unsplash.com/photos/f84q9AsoaRI" > Click me </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: why are you using `z-index` at all? It's entirely unnecessary?

Comment: I used the z-index because the background image on top of both the childs were not displaying. is there any solution without z-index please share it

Comment: Through css, you could use the attribute "pointer-events: none" to ignore an event on the element that is getting in the way, but in your case, you are using z-index wrong, the z-index, should be 0, 1, 2 to childrens... -1, it's a hack.

Comment: @IvanFerrer I want to perform action on the divs. In first child i have anchor tag which will redirect me to another page. The problem is  can't access  the child divs elements. You got my point ?

Comment: I understand the point, but it is not accessing it because there is an element on top, which is preventing the selection, the problem is that there are better ways to organize these elements without having to use the z-index, but there is this workaround, of putting "pointer- events: none" on that element that is on top.

Comment: I cannot figure out the solution. I don't think so by giving pointer events none to parent will work. I tried but still the issue is not resolved.

Comment: Two problems are having when i set the background by giving childs -1 i cannot perform events and when i remove z-index the background image not show

Comment: Sample example: https://jsfiddle.net/rycdtx8z/1/

Comment: @IvanFerrer thanks. I think this is the only way to solve the problem. But it it affecting the structure

Answer (score -1):

Use the `backgroung: url('Your url') no-repeat;`
For more info read the documentation [Background img documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.php)

Comment: Yes i try this. The background image is not showing when i set the second div's z-index to 2.